# How do you create Windows security descriptors in managed code?

Tags: c#, .net, security, winapi, named-pipes

I have a named pipe that's created in a managed process. I have a 2nd process that tries to open a file handle to the named pipe, however the 2nd process is running under an lower privilege than the process that created the named pipe. My understanding is that I need to create the named pipe in the first process with a security descriptor like the one described in this MSKB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813414

The problem is that I am not sure how to do this in managed code, the KB article uses C++. Does anyone know of a way to create the named pipe so that it can be read and written to anonymously, preferably using a security descriptor? Lowering the privileges of the first process that created the named pipe is not an option, I need it to be running with high privileges.

Answer (score 5):

You can [pinvoke the ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257349(VS.80).aspx) and pass a [security descriptor in SDDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379567(VS.85).aspx). If you want detailed control on the describer, you can find wrapper classes in open source communities, such as [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/accessctrl3.aspx#History). [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163883.aspx#S6) is an examples to use the security descriptor on named pipes.